# connect to remote server using sockets unix

Tags: sockets, unix

In unix, I want to make a client program connect to a server running on different machine. For this, I need to enter the ip address of server through keyboard and then pass that ip address in the connect() system call of client. I tried reading as a string, and passing it.But it didnt work. Is there any specific way to pass the ip address?

Comment: Start at [`ip(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), and maybe take a look at [`tcp(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) and [`socket(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) while you're at it.  And [`ipv6(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html), come to think of it.

Comment: Please show your code. What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IPv4, the function you're looking for is `inet_addr`, which converts the string representation of an IPv4 address to a numerical value which can be passed into various socket functions:

```
int get_connection(const char *ip, int port)
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in sin;

  bzero(&sin,sizeof(sin));
  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  sin.sin_port = htons(port);

  if ((sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1) {
    perror("Error creating socket");
    return -1;
  }
  if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin))==-1) {
    perror("Couldn't connect");
    close(sock);
    return -1;
  }
  return sock;
}
```

Comment: @teja Did this answer your question?